# Why does this ajax form not insert records?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a form that will be used to edit records in a mysql database. The form is inside a bootstrap modal and I am trying to get it to submit with ajax without any luck. I get a success message but it flashes up only very quickly and no record gets inserted into the database.

Please can someone help. I'm sure it will be an error with my jquery as I've spent a long time trying to figure out (along with much help from here) how to pass varibles into the modal. Many thanks.

The jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var review = $(e.relatedTarget).data('review');
        var username = $(e.relatedTarget).data('username');
        var film_id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('film_id');
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="review"]').val(review);
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="username"]').val(username);
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="film_id"]').val(film_id);
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="id"]').val(id);
    });
    $("#submitButtonId").on("click",function(){
        var username = $(this).data("username");
        var film_id = $(this).data('film_id');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var review = $(this).data('review');

        $.post('ajax_insert.php', {username: username, film_id: film_id, id: id, review: review},
               function(data){
                   $('#my_modal').modal('hide');
                   $("#message").html(data);
                   $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
                   $("#message").fadeOut(500);
               });
    });
});
</script>
```

The form

```
<div class="container">
  <body>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-review="A masterpiece brillopads." data-id="517" data-username="julian" data-film_id="21641">Open Modal</a>
<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
          Modal header
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        <form>
          <p>
            some content
          </p>
          <input type="text" name="review" value="">
          <input type="text" name="username" value="">
          <input type="text" name="film_id" value="">
          <input type="text" name="id" value="">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
        <button type="submit" id="submitButtonId" class="btn btn-primary">
          Save changes
        </button>
      </form>
```

ajax_insert.php

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("ajax_review/config.php");
//Configure and Connect to the Databse
if (!$mysqli) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$username=$_POST['username'];
$film_id=$_POST['film_id'];
$review=$_POST['review'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
//Insert Data into mysql
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ajax_test(username,film_id,id,review) VALUES('$username','$film_id','$id','$review'");
if($insert_row){
    echo 'Success';
}
else{ echo "An error occurred!"; }
?>
```

Comment: You're using `$(this).data("username")` when `this` is the submit button. But the data fields are in the anchor element, not the submit button.

Comment: you have no ids for `input type="text" name="review" value="">
          <input type="text" name="username" value="">
          <input type="text" name="film_id" value="">`

Comment: check for errors and your developer console.

Comment: Why do they need IDs?

Comment: @Barmar don't they? seems like it, unless I missed something

Comment: Only if you want to access them by ID, e.g. `$("#review")`. He's accessing them by name with `$("input[name=review]")`.

Comment: I hope this isn't a live site. Because if it is, it's open an SQL injection. Plus, if there are any characters being inserted that MySQL will complain about, then you'll need to escape your data. Something you should be doing anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It's not live yet no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the variables like `username` to `$(this).data("username")`. But there's no `data-username` attribute in the submit button, so you're sending empty values to the server.

I guess you intended to get them from the anchor that opens the modal. But that's not right, those are just the initial values, not the values after the user has edited them. The updated values are in the form fields. You can use `.serialize` to convert all the form fields into form data.

```
$("#submitButtonId").on("click",function(){
    var formdata = $(this.form).serialize();
    $.post('ajax_insert.php', formdata,
           function(data){
               $('#my_modal').modal('hide');
               $("#message").html(data);
               $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
               $("#message").fadeOut(500);
           });
});
```

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know that, given what the OP posted for code, have tested it and with your answer, and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments. I've been trying to get the above code to work but the php page reports back an error . I'm using firebug to try and figure out what's wrong, I can see it posting to the php form but the firebug console goes blank a second later...

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what PHP is sending back.

Comment: It looks like the variables are being sent to ajax_insert.php but the page is highlighted in red and I think is reporting as being 'stalled'. Earlier I tried at and the Network said ajax_insert.php was cancelled.

Comment: Check the log on the server to see if there's a PHP error.

Comment: The server log reports each of the variables being received by ajax_insert.php as being  'undefined'. I am receiving them in php like this $username=$_POST['username'];

Comment: It works! Apologies, I had a stray parenthesis in the php file. I really appreciate your help and patience. Thank you.